# Set Product as New From/To fields are not shown on product settings page

Tags: admin, magento2.3.4

I can't see the options **"Set Product as New From"** and **"Set Product as New To"** option fields on product settings page. I only see a toggle button says "Set Product as New" instead.

I couldn't find any information about this, it seems like nobody faced this issue or this is not an issue actually.

I checked on a clean install of Magento 2 but it's same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: can you check Attribute Set Migration_Default has both attribute in group??
if not then you can add to your Attribute set.

Comment: Both are in the attribute set. https://cln.sh/iYaDWd

Comment: @mapetek, How you fixed this ?

Comment: @SunnyRahevar We couldn't fix this. Since we're using Adobe Commerce on Cloud, we have the scheduling functionality. Setting a start and an end date solves our issue.

https://share.cleanshot.com/1NnTNpwn